# Aggregate to Get totals of key value pairs in array, grouping on the field values for similar names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents that are structured like below, where each array element contains "n" and "v" as the key and value for different types of data. I need to group this by the "n" values for "ipaddress" and count the total distinct combination from the collection. However, values are similar but not the same. (ex: ip, ip_addr and ipaddr)

```
> db.final.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "props" : [
                {
                        "n" : "loc",
                        "v" : "NW"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "logtype",
                        "v" : "1"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "ip",
                        "v" : "1.1.1.1"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "pro",
                        "v" : "tcp"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "port",
                        "v" : "13438"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 5,
        "props" : [
                {
                        "n" : "loc",
                        "v" : "NW"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "logtype",
                        "v" : "1"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "ip",
                        "v" : "1.1.1.1"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "pro",
                        "v" : "tcp"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "port",
                        "v" : "53"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "props" : [
                {
                        "n" : "loc",
                        "v" : "NW"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "logtype",
                        "v" : "2"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "ip_addr",
                        "v" : "2.2.2.2"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "pro",
                        "v" : "udp"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "port",
                        "v" : "53"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 3,
        "props" : [
                {
                        "n" : "loc",
                        "v" : "NW"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "logtype",
                        "v" : "3"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "ipaddr",
                        "v" : "1.1.1.1"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "pro",
                        "v" : "tcp"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "port",
                        "v" : "53"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 4,
        "props" : [
                {
                        "n" : "loc",
                        "v" : "LA"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "logtype",
                        "v" : "3"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "ipaddr",
                        "v" : "1.1.1.1"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "pro",
                        "v" : "udp"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "port",
                        "v" : "53"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 6,
        "props" : [
                {
                        "n" : "loc",
                        "v" : "LA"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "logtype",
                        "v" : "1"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "ip",
                        "v" : "1.1.1.1"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "pro",
                        "v" : "udp"
                },
                {
                        "n" : "port",
                        "v" : "53"
                }
        ]
}
```

The Query selection conditions like this:

1. if "loc" is "NW" and "logtype" is "1" then "ipaddress" = "ip"
2. if "loc" is "NW" and "logtype" is "2" then "ipaddress" = "ip_addr"
3. if "loc" is "NW" and "logtype" is "3" then "ipaddress" = "ipaddr"
4. port is "53"
5. pro is 'udp' or 'tcp'
6. Group by "ipaddress"

I want a result like this.

```
{"ipaddress" : "2.2.2.2" , count : 1}
{"ipaddress" : "1.1.1.1" , count : 2}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
db.final.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "$and": [
            {"props" : {"$elemMatch": { "n": "port", "v": "53" }}},
            {"props" : {"$elemMatch": { "n": "pro", "v": {"$in" : [/udp/, /tcp/]} }}}
        ]
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$props" },
        {
        "$project": {
            "_ipaddress": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": { "$eq": [ "$props.n", "ip" ] },
                    "then": "$props.v",
                    "else": {
                        "$cond": {
                            "if": { "$eq": [ "$props.n", "ip_addr" ] },
                            "then": "$props.v",
                            "else": {
                                "$cond" : {
                                    "if": { "$eq": [ "$props.n", "ipaddr" ] },
                                    "then": "$props.v",
                                    "else" : 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "_id": 1,
            "props" : 1
        }
    },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "_ipaddress": {
            "$min": {
                "$cond": [ { "$ne": [ "$_ipaddress", 0 ] }, "$_ipaddress", false ]
            }
        },
        "pro": {
            "$min": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$props.n", "pro" ] }, "$props.v", false ]
            }
        },
        "logtype": {
            "$min": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$props.n", "logtype" ] }, "$props.v", false ]
            }
        },
        "port": {
            "$min": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$props.n", "port" ] }, "$props.v", false ]
            }
        }
    } },
        { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_ipaddress": "$_ipaddress",
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

But I don't know how to combine "loc" and "logtype" condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here each document has an array which collectively storing related information.This design is not well suited for the query your are trying to.
As per my understanding $unwind can't help much here,as it will split array elements.

Solution I found is  to make your array elements to a key:value pairs and succeeded to an extend .

```
> db.final.aggregate([
 ... {"$project" : {"pro" : { "$setDifference" :[{"$map" : {"input" : "$props","as" : "array_elem", "in" : { "$cond" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$$array_elem.n", "pro" ] }, "$$array_elem.v", null]}}}, [null] ] },props:1}},
 ... {"$project" : {"loc" : { "$setDifference" :[{"$map" : {"input" : "$props","as" : "array_elem", "in" : { "$cond" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$$array_elem.n", "loc" ] }, "$$array_elem.v", null]}}}, [null] ] },props:1,pro:1}},
 ... {"$project" : {"port" : { "$setDifference" :[{"$map" : {"input" : "$props","as" : "array_elem", "in" : { "$cond" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$$array_elem.n", "port" ] }, "$$array_elem.v", null]}}}, [null] ] },props:1,pro:1,loc:1}},
 ... {"$project" : {"ip" : { "$setDifference" :[{"$map" : {"input" : "$props","as" : "array_elem", "in" : { "$cond" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$$array_elem.n", "ip" ] }, "$$array_elem.v", null]}}}, [null] ] },props:1,pro:1,loc:1,port:1}},
 ... {"$project" : {"ip_addr" : { "$setDifference" :[{"$map" : {"input" : "$props","as" : "array_elem", "in" : { "$cond" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$$array_elem.n", "ip_addr" ] }, "$$array_elem.v", null]}}}, [null] ] },props:1,pro:1,loc:1,port:1,ip:1}},
 ... {"$project" : {"ipaddr" : { "$setDifference" :[{"$map" : {"input" : "$props","as" : "array_elem", "in" : { "$cond" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$$array_elem.n", "ipaddr" ] }, "$$array_elem.v", null]}}}, [null] ] },pro:1,loc:1,port:1,ip:1,ip_addr:1}}
 ... ])

//Result(I have used data given in your question):
{ "_id" : 2, "pro" : [ "tcp" ], "loc" : [ "NW" ], "port" : [ "13438" ], "ip" : [ "1.1.1.1" ], "ip_addr" : [ ], "ipaddr" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "pro" : [ "tcp" ], "loc" : [ "NW" ], "port" : [ "53" ], "ip" : [ "1.1.1.1" ], "ip_addr" : [ ], "ipaddr" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "pro" : [ "udp" ], "loc" : [ "NW" ], "port" : [ "53" ], "ip" : [ ], "ip_addr" : [ "2.2.2.2" ], "ipaddr" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "pro" : [ "tcp" ], "loc" : [ "NW" ], "port" : [ "53" ], "ip" : [ ], "ip_addr" : [ ], "ipaddr" : [ "1.1.1.1" ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "pro" : [ "udp" ], "loc" : [ "LA" ], "port" : [ "53" ], "ip" : [ ], "ip_addr" : [ ], "ipaddr" : [ "1.1.1.1" ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "pro" : [ "udp" ], "loc" : [ "LA" ], "port" : [ "53" ], "ip" : [ "1.1.1.1" ], "ip_addr" : [ ], "ipaddr" : [ ] }
```

Here each element in Array is  key and value.You can apply conditions on this documents and get desired result.I'm not giving here the full answer as you have done it already partial.

Note :

1. MongoDB don't  allow to use $elemMatch in aggregation(https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14876) And the work-around used for that is increasing size of aggregation pipeline.
2. If position of elements in array is dependable it can be used simply to convert array elements to key:vale pairs.